# passing vars from Index View to Create View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, razor

I have 2 dropdownlists on the Index page, and I wish to pass the id's of the selected items to the Create Page, so that I can populate the 2 dropdownlists on the Create page the same as the Index page.

Can you please suggest how I can do this?

At the moment I have this in the Index View :-

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { LeagueId = "ddlLeagues" }, new { ClubId = "ddlClubs" })
```

And then in the Controller :-

```
        public ActionResult Create(int LeagueId, int ClubId)
    {
        var _LeagueID = LeagueId;
        var _ClubID = ClubId;
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check out my updated solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as described in this post:

[ActionLink routeValue from a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838273/actionlink-routevalue-from-a-textbox)

you basically need to wrap your dropdowns with a form that routes to the create function, and the submit will take care of passing those values to your controller because they will be in the form data:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Footballer", FormMethod.Get))
{
  @Html.DropDownList("LeagueId", Model.Leagues)
  @Html.DropDownList("ClubId", Model.Clubs)

  <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
}
```

If you are using a strongly typed model that has Properties for LeagueId and ClubId then use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LeagueId, Model.Leagues)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClubId, Model.Clubs)
```

Model.Clubs and Model.League are the IEnumerables that you will use to populate your dropDowns ofcourse

in your controller make sure you have the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionMethod Create(int LeagueId, int ClubId)
{
  //return your Create View
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionMethod Create(FormCollection data)
{
  //Perform the create here
}
```

Comment: Hi Bassam, when doing as you said I am getting the following :- http://localhost:7246/Footballer/Create?LeagueId=ddlLeagues&ClubId=ddlClubs

Comment: @Johann this will pass them into your controller, if they are defined in your route that's how they will be sent, as a part of the RequestString

Comment: Hi Bassam, but what I want is for example :-http://localhost:7246/Footballer/Create?LeagueId=1&ClubId=5.  How can I get that?

Comment: We cannot see you localhost because it's local. You need to send us an IP address that is not local.

Comment: I know Patrick, but this is a test app that is still on my local.  I just need to know how to get the ID's

Comment: Bassam I tried your solution but no luck, did not even hit the Create Action in the Controller.  I also tried the following :-   @using(Html.BeginForm("Create"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new { LeagueId = "ddlLeagues", ClubId = "ddlClubs" })
but I got the same error

Comment: with your solution did not hit the Create Action in the controller, with mine is the same error

Comment: Try including the controller name (check the updated solution)

Comment: with your solution (input button) its going directly in the ActionResult (Post) action, which is not good cause I need to get the Create Page first

Comment: @BassamMehanni I did not have time to work on this these last couple of days since its a side project.  Will get back to it in the weekend, and will let you know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route into the application `RegisterRoutes` :

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "CreateFootBallerWith2ComboOptions",
        "{controller}/{action}/{LeagueId}/{ClubId}",                           
        new { controller = "Footballer", action = "Create", LeagueId = -1, ClubId = -1 }  // Default Values
    );
```

You can then use what Bassam suggest with the ActionLink which is a Html Helper.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", 
                new { LeagueId = 1, ClubId = 213 });
```

or use directly from the browser using :

```
localhost:7246/Footballer/Create/1/5
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, but how will I get the 1 and 213 in new { LeagueId = 1, ClubId = 213 })?  How can I get the selected Value?

Comment: Well, it's you to provide those 1 and 5 the way you want. You can use Javascript or with ASP generate the link. You are the developer and you are the only one to know how you would prefer to implement. You could create the combo into a form which be sent automatically to the server.