# Replacing parent view with partial view from another partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
This My Parent View In this i am calling partialview(_CityList.cshtml).



@model MedicalOrbit.City
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateCity";
}

<h2>Add City</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


       <div id="Maindiv" class="col-lg-7">

        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
            <div class="ibox-title">
                <h5>City Details</h5>
                <div class="ibox-tools">
                    <a class="collapse-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 b-r">
                        @*<hr />*@
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>City Name:</label>

                            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
                            <br>
                            <div >
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CityName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter City" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br>
                            <div>

                                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" />
                                &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" />

                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="CityList" class="col-sm-6">
                            @*@Html.Partial("_CityList");*@
                            @Html.Action("CityList", "City")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}




<div id="Editdiv">
    @Html.Action("EditCity", "City")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


Partial View(_CityList.cshtml)

 <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CityName)
            </th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityName)
                </td>
                <td>

                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CityID })*@ 
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit City", "EditCity", "City", new AjaxOptions()
               {
                   UpdateTargetId = "Maindiv",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.ReplaceWith
               })|
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CityID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CityID })  |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Area", "Area", new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-lg fa fa-times", id = item.CityID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>



following is my Controller Code




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MedicalOrbit.Controllers
{
    public class CityController : Controller
    {
        MediOrbitDatabaseEntities db = new MediOrbitDatabaseEntities();
        // GET: City
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult CityList()
        {
            return PartialView("_CityList", db.Cities.Where(x => x.status == false).ToList());

        }

        public ActionResult CreateCity()
        {

            return View();
        }

        // POST: City/CreateCity
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateCity(City city)
        {

                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    city.Users = "ashwini";
                    city.DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    city.status = false;

                    db.Cities.Add(city);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("CreateCity");

                }
            return View(city);
        }

        public ActionResult EditCity(int? id)
        {
            City city = db.Cities.Where(x => x.CityID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (city == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(city);
        }
        // POST: /Admin/City/Edit
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditCity(City city)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                city.Users = "Ashwini";
                city.DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                city.status = false;

                db.Entry(city).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                RedirectToAction("CreateCity");
            }

            return PartialView("_EditCity",city);

        }


    }
}
```

Now what i want is in _CityList.cshtml partial view when user clicks the edit actionlink then main parent view should be replace with another partial view(_EditCity.cshmtl).how i can achieve this.i m not experience in mvc so plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am showing you how to do partial views.  Hopefully, you will have enough take away to utilize partial views within partial views, if you want.

There might be extra code to help you.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexValid4</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#LOCATION_NUMBER').click(function () {
                var store = $('#storeNbr').val();
                this.href = this.href.split("?")[0];
                this.href = this.href + '?LOCATION_NUMBER=' + encodeURIComponent(store);
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">My Modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <label class="btnIEFix">You can also, Click in Grey Area Outside Modal To Close</label>
                    <button title="You can also, Click in Grey Area Outside Modal To Close" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary bootBtnMargin" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(r => r.storeNbr, new { id = "storeNbr" })
    @*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838273/actionlink-routevalue-from-a-textbox*@
    @Ajax.ActionLink(
                                   "Trigger Ajax",
                                            "ReleaseVersion",
                                       null,
                                       new AjaxOptions
                                        {
                                            UpdateTargetId = "result",
                                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                            HttpMethod = "GET"
                                        },
                                                new
                                                {
                                                    id = "LOCATION_NUMBER"})
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult ReleaseVersion(string LOCATION_NUMBER = "")
    {
        return PartialView("_ReleaseVersion");  //, model
    }

    public ActionResult IndexValid4()
    {
        var storeViewModel = new StoreViewModel { storeNbr = 5 };
        return View(storeViewModel);
    }
```

_ReleaseVersion partial view in shared folder:

```
release version partial view
```

Comment: @Ash I redid my post.