# Implement and populate view model db first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have created a page were the user searches for a book and the book details are loaded using partial view. I have successfully done this.
The action method in the controller used to do this:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoanSearch(string q)
    {
        var loans = GetLoans(q);

        return PartialView(loans);
    }
    private List<Loan> GetLoans(string searchString)
    {

        return db.Loans
            .Where(a => a.Book.Name.Contains(searchString))
            .ToList();
    }
```

As you can see the LoanSearch action method is decorated with HTTPGET.

The View for this:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@item.ISBN</li>
        <li>@item.Book.Name</li>
        <li>@item.Book.Author</li>

        <li> @item.FinePrice</li>
    </ul>


        @Html.ActionLink("Return Book", "LoanSearch", new { id = item.LoanId });
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is update the finePrice in loans db and change onLoan from 1 to 0 in the books db. This should happen when the user clicks on the above Html.ActionLink above.

To achieve this I created the following HTTPPOST action method and also used a view model as I needed to update 2 tables (Loan,Book) at the same time.(is a view model needed?)

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoanSearch(BookReturnVM model, string searchString)
    {

                    var bookquery = db.Loans.Where(a => a.Book.Name.Contains(searchString));

        var loanquery = db.Loans.Where(a => a.Book.Name == model.BookTitle);

        var finePrice = db.Loans.Where(g => g.FinePrice == model.FinePrice);



        BookReturnVM model1 = new BookReturnVM
        {

            OnLoan = model.OnLoan,
            FinePrice = model.FinePrice,


        };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)

        {

            var fine = db.Loans.FirstOrDefault(g => g.FinePrice == model.FinePrice);

            var bookLoan = db.Loans.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Book.Name.Contains(searchString));

            if (bookLoan != null)

            {   //changes the onloan status to 1 which makes it 'on loan'


                bookLoan.Book.OnLoan = 0;


            };
 db.Entry(bookLoan).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
            return View();
```

I would like the finePrice found in the Loan table to be updated based on the calculation below. The finePrice calculation is done in the Loan model:

```
   private decimal? _FinePrice;
    public decimal? FinePrice

    {
        get
        {
             if(DateTime.Now>CheckOutDate)
            {
                this._FinePrice= ((DateTime.Now - CheckOutDate).Days)*0.50M;
            }
            else
            {
                this._FinePrice = 0M;
            }

            return this._FinePrice;
        }
          set
        {

            this._FinePrice = value;

        }
    }
```

In conclusion when I search for a book, the details of the book appears(in partial view,which it does), and when I click a button(on the same partial view page) the OnLoan (book table) changes from 1 to 0 and the finePrice (loan table)is updated for that particular book.

I assume the problem lies within the HTTP POST action method but do not know how to solve this in order to solve the above question.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I'm sorry, but what seems to be the problem? Is there an error you're getting?

Comment: I want to create a link in the partial view that updates the fineprice in the loan table and changes the onloan in the book table to 0. The fineprice is calculated in the loan domain model

Comment: OK, well, considering that your method is marked as `HttpPost`, you will need to use some javascript to post the form data, as opposed to a simple link which results in a GET. If you are using jQuery in your project, you will want to look into using `$.post`.

Comment: I was using html.beginform() in partial view. should I place the form method in here as post? I  think my code in the action method post is incorrect as my database should change/update?

Comment: When you click on the link, is it actually hitting your `LoanSearch` method? This sort of goes back to my first comment - what is the actual problem that you're encountering?

Comment: yes it is hitting the LoanSearch method. I just do know how to update my database. the code in the http post method is incorrect? as the database is not being updated. how do I update the database? in particular the fineprice (loan table) and the onloan (book table) columns. the onloan should be updated and should have value of 0, the fineprice should be a price based on the calculation done in the loan model

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Tables:

```
USE [Breaz]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Loan]    Script Date: 6/26/2017 11:15:15 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Loan](
    [LoanId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ISBN] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Author] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [FinePrice] [money] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Loan] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoanId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult LoanSearchByIdAndUpdate(int id)
    {
        //DO your database update here
        //I will change the find to 2.37
        Loan loan = new Loan();
        var bookName = String.Empty;
        using (BreazEntities26 db = new BreazEntities26())
        {
            loan = db.Loans.Find(id);
            loan.FinePrice = 2.37M;
            bookName = loan.Name;
        }
        IList<Loan> loans = new List<Loan>();
        loans.Add(loan);
        return PartialView("_LoanSearch", loans););
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult LoanSearch(string q)
    {
        var loans = GetLoans(q);

        return PartialView("_LoanSearch", loans););
    }

    private List<Loan> GetLoans(string searchString)
    {
        using (BreazEntities26 db = new BreazEntities26())
        {
            return db.Loans
           .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(searchString))
           .ToList();
        }
    }
```

IndexValid2.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexValid2</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    @*MAKE SURE to put the next script in*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#passSearchValue').click(function () {
                var searchValue = $('#q').val();
                this.href = this.href + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchValue);
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Search for book:
        @Html.TextBox("q", null, new { id = "q" })
        @*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838273/actionlink-routevalue-from-a-textbox*@
        @Ajax.ActionLink(
                               "Search",
                                "LoanSearch",
                                   null,
                                   new AjaxOptions
                                    {
                                        UpdateTargetId = "result",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        HttpMethod = "GET"
                                    },
                                    new { id = "passSearchValue" })
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

partial view in shared, _LoanSearch.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Testy20161006.Models.Loan>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@item.ISBN</li>
        <li>@item.Name</li>
        <li>@item.Author</li>

        <li> @item.FinePrice</li>
    </ul>
    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "LoanSearchByIdAndUpdate", new { id = item.LoanId });
    <p />
    @Html.ActionLink("Return to Search", "IndexValid2");
}
```